# What's the standard error of a proportion where there are multiple groups?

Tags: standard-error, proportion, group-differences

If I have a sample with groups `x, y, z`, where there are 300 of `x`, 600 of `y`, and `100` of `z`, how do I find the standard error for the proportion of these?

I have

- x : 0.3
- y : 0.6
- z : 0.1

If I google for the standard error of a proportion I get

$$
se = \sqrt{
\frac{pq}{n}
}
$$

Which seems to suggest that I would have

- sx : `sqrt((0.3)(0.7) / 1000) =~ 0.014`
- sy : `sqrt((0.6)(0.4) / 1000) =~ 0.015`
- sz : `sqrt((0.1)(0.9) / 1000) =~ 0.009`

Is this correct? For some reason, I thought that this formula was for two groups, rather than multiple.

This would give confidence intervals of (for `x`):

- ci_x : `.3 +- 1.96 * (0.014) =~ (0.27, 0.32)`

Answer (score 2):

The formula works fine for any number of groups.  The standard error represents the uncertainty in the observed proportion of one group versus "the rest", and this uncertainty doesn't change whether "the rest" consists of one, two, or fifty groups.

So, the proportion of "x" in your sample is 0.3 +/- 0.014, and this estimate and standard error stay the same even if we later discover that "y" consisted of three subgroups we didn't previously notice.

(You might want to check your rounding on your confidence interval, though.  I get 0.33 for the upper bound.)

Comment: "You might want to check your rounding on your confidence interval", cheers - i was pretty loose with the rounding :)