# How do I calculate error margins for difference in proportions?

Tags: confidence-interval, proportion, error-propagation

I have data that captures responses to stimuli and categorises both the cue stimuli and response stimuli for both male and female, as follows:

| Cue Stimulus | Response Stimulus | Gender | Cue Count | Cue Proportion | Response Count | Response Proportion |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | A | F | 5,365 | 6.74% | 7,565 | 9.5% |
| A | A | M | 3,588 | 4.32% | 6,102 | 10.40% |
| B | B | F | 3,443 | 6.74% | 4,669 | 5.86% |
| B | B | M | 2,598 | 4.43% | 3,177 | 5.42% |

This means that Females have been given cue Stimulus category **A** 5,365 times (6.74% of female cues). Females have responded with Stimulus category **A** 7,565 times (9.5% of female responses). The overall number of cue-response pairs is $79,625 F$ and $58,645 M$. The responses were given by $37,188$ female and $24,732$ male participants.

Participants answered a minimum of 1 time and a maximum of 10 times. The mean and standard deviation of the count of responses is below.

| gender | mean number of responses | std |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Fe | 2.141148 | 1.376285 |
| Ma | 2.371219 | 1.440570 |

I want to understand if Females or Males have tendencies to respond more frequently in any of the categories.

I have attempted to calculate an error margin for each row based on another [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/467347/whats-the-standard-error-of-a-proportion-where-there-are-multiple-groups):

$$
se = \sqrt{
\frac{pq}{n}
}
$$

Would the error margin for 1.96 Confidence Interval be as follows, for the first row of data?

$$
E = \pm\sqrt{0.095*(1-0.095) / 79,625}*1.96 = \pm0.2\%
$$

I then calculated the *difference* between the cue proportions and the response proportions. e.g. the first line difference would be $9.5\% - 6.74\% = 2.76\%$. Is it valid to use the error margin obtained above for this result? e.g. $2.76\% \pm 0.2\%$

Comment: Does your sample consist of 79625 women? If not I think we need more details and your analysis may well become more complicated.

Comment: No, it consists of 79,625 responses given by 37,188 women. There were 24,732 male participants.

Comment: Then it's important to report more details of the experiment and its results. For instance, it's possible 37,187 women gave one response each and one woman gave 42,438 responses, and obviously that should alter your estimate of the se.

Comment: Ok, so I should include an average number of responses per male and female?

Comment: Averages might or might not suffice, depending on the experimental design. For instance, an experiment where additional stimuli were provided to some subjects in response to their initial results needs a different form of analysis than an experiment where everyone was given the same number of randomly chosen stimuli. (And there are a huge number of other possible designs beyond those two.)

Comment: I've added the mean and std of the number of responses by males and females. The stimuli were single words chosen at random for each person (a cue), to which they replied with a word that came to mind (a response). I guess I'm making the assumption that the individual words do not matter, as my sample size is large and the words had been pre-filtered to a list of words not expected to prompt common responses. The words are placed in categories, which I've referenced in my question.